# Mock Mailer in Symfony service

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, symfony

I want to unit test this simple service:

```
/**
 * Class Messager
 * @package AppBundle\Services
 */
class Messager
{

    private $mailer = null;
    private $templating = null;

    /**
     * Messager constructor.
     * @param \Swift_Mailer $mailer
     */
    public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer, TwigEngine $templating)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }

    /**
     * Send mail
     * @param string $email
     * @param string $message
     * @return bool
     */
    public function handleMessage(string $email, string $content) : bool
    {
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) || strlen($content) < 25) {
            return false;
        }
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('[DadaPleasure] Incoming message from user')
        ->setFrom($email)
        ->setTo('my.e@mail.com')
        ->setBody($this->templating->render('Emails/contact.html.twig', array('email' => $email, 'message' => $content)), 'text/html');
    $this->mailer->send($message);
    return true;
    }
}
```

So, I'm doing this currently:

```
class MessagerTest extends TestConfig
{
    public function testSendWrongMessage()
    {
        $mailer = $this->getMockBuilder('Swift_Mailer')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
        self::$container->set('swiftmailer.mailer.default', $mailer);

        $this->assertFalse(self::$container->get('app.messager')->handleMessage('hello', 'world'));
        $mailer->expects($this->never())->method('send');
    }

    public function testSendValidEmail()
    {
        $mailer = $this->getMockBuilder('Swift_Mailer')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
        $messager = new Messager($mailer, self::$container->get('templating'));

        $this->assertTrue($messager->handleMessage('me@myself.com', 'worldworldworldworldworld'));
        $mailer->expects($this->once())->method('send');
    }
}
```

But it seems like `send` is never called because I got this return:

> Expectation failed for method name is equal to  when invoked 1 time(s).
>   Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.

If I add `var_dump`, my function pass by `$this-mailer->send` but I don't know why the assert fails.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: probably append  `->with($this->anything())` at the end ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the expectation declaration before the utilisation, as example:

```
$mailer->expects($this->once())->method('send');
$messager = new Messager($mailer, self::$container->get('templating'));

$this->assertTrue($messager->handleMessage('me@myself.com', 'worldworldworldworldworld'));
```

Hope this help

Comment: Yesss!  That fixed the issue.  Thanks a lot!